# How to get IdentityUser by Username

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-identity

I have previously worked with Membership through "System.Web.Security.Membership"

Here, you can do the following:

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
var otherUser = Membership.GetUser(username);
```

...giving you a MembershipUser.

Now, with Identity, I can find a load of ways to get the **current logged in user**.
But no way to get another user.

I can use:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
var user = userManager.Find(username, password);
```

But that takes both username and password, with no overload for just username.

How do i get the IdentityUser from only a username?

Almost every answer I find is connected to MVC.
This is for a WCF service, where authorization is made using Identity. And in some cases the user is getting to the site from an other site with a generated "token" - an encrypted string, containing the username. From here, user is logged in and a session-cookie is set, depending on users settings.

Also, is there a shorter way to get UserInformation?

"var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(username);"

is much more convenient than

"var user2 = (new UserManager((new UserStore()))).Find(username, password);"

Answer (score 1):

`UserManager` has [`UserManager<TUser>.FindByNameAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbynameasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method. You can try using it to find user by name.